# Query fired from C# driver to locally hosted Mongodb server

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using C# mongodb driver 2.4.4. 
I want to see what query or the request my c# code is making to mongodb server.

Is there a way I can check what all requests have come to my mongo db server in a particular time frame ??  Is there a way I can capture the requests to my mongodb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to enable profiling on the database, if you drop in to the mongo console and call `setProfilingLevel` setting with a parameter of `2` (all).

```
> db.setProfilingLevel(2, 0)
{ "was" : 0, "slowms" : 100, "sampleRate" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
```

Next within your C# when you create the `MongoClient` pass in an `MongoClientSettings` object with an unique `ApplicationName`. This is so we can filter the results later.

```
var client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings()
{
    ApplicationName = "Sackoverflow-Question-53393041"
});

var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");

collection.InsertOne(new BsonDocument()
{
    {"_id", 1 }
});
```

Now when our application runs any operations against mongodb they'll get profiled. To view what our application has run on mongodb we can run the following query within the mongo console:

```
> db.system.profile.find({"appName": "Sackoverflow-Question-53393041"}).pretty()
```

> Notice that we query using the `appName` which we set in our C# code, this allows us to narrow down our queries. You can also query any other part of the profile document too such as command (insert, query etc..)

With our above query the following will get outputted to the console.

```
{
        "op" : "insert",
        "ns" : "test.test",
        "command" : {
                "insert" : "test",
                "ordered" : true,
                "$db" : "test",
                "lsid" : {
                        "id" : UUID("4727f842-a50c-488d-a18a-f9830cac018d")
                }
        },
        "ninserted" : 1,
        "keysInserted" : 1,
        "numYield" : 0,
        "locks" : {
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(5),
                                "w" : NumberLong(3)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                                "w" : NumberLong(2),
                                "W" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                                "w" : NumberLong(2)
                        }
                }
        },
        "responseLength" : 29,
        "protocol" : "op_msg",
        "millis" : 21,
        "ts" : ISODate("2018-12-01T15:33:42.526Z"),
        "client" : "127.0.0.1",
        "appName" : "Sackoverflow-Question-53393041",
        "allUsers" : [ ],
        "user" : ""
}
```

This also works with queries, So if we execute the following in C#

```
var result = collection.Find(x => x["_id"] == 1);
```

We'll get the following profile document

```
{
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "test.test",
        "command" : {
                "find" : "test",
                "filter" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "$db" : "test"
        },
        "keysExamined" : 1,
        "docsExamined" : 1,
        "cursorExhausted" : true,
        "numYield" : 0,
        "locks" : {
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(2)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                }
        },
        "nreturned" : 1,
        "responseLength" : 99,
        "protocol" : "op_msg",
        "millis" : 1,
        "planSummary" : "IDHACK",
        "execStats" : {
                "stage" : "IDHACK",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 2,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keysExamined" : 1,
                "docsExamined" : 1
        },
        "ts" : ISODate("2018-12-01T15:35:31.150Z"),
        "client" : "127.0.0.1",
        "appName" : "Sackoverflow-Question-53393041",
        "allUsers" : [ ],
        "user" : ""
}
```

As you said you need it in a given date range so you can query the `"ts"` field with the following query

```
> db.system.profile.find( { "appName" : "Sackoverflow-Question-53393041", $and : [ { "ts" : { $gt : ISODate("2018-12-01") } }, { "ts" : { $lt : ISODate("2018-12-02") } } ] } ).pretty()
```